# Como armazenar valores de uma função recursiva em um array?

Tags: php

Já tentei passar um array como parâmetro, mas retornou somente o primeiro valor do contador. Qual a forma correta de se retornar um array com todos os valores dentro em uma função recursiva?
Segue a função com retorno de array:

Segue a função inicial:

```
function minhaFuncao($contador)
{
if($contador < 10)
{
    echo "O contador agora é: ".$contador."<br>";
    $contador++;
    minhaFuncao($contador);
}
    return true;
}

minhaFuncao(1);
```

Segue função com tentativa para retorno com array:

```
function minhaFuncao($contador, $lista = array())
{
if($contador < 10)
{
    echo "O contador agora é: ".$contador."<br>";
    $lista[] = $contador;
    $contador++;
    minhaFuncao($contador);
}
    return $lista;
}

print_r(minhaFuncao(1));
```

Comment: Se a resposta em baixo explicou o problema e o resolveu pode marcar a resposta como certa...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que você não está passando o array como parâmetro e nem retornando o valor da chamada recursiva.

Você pode fazer assim:

```
function minhaFuncao($contador, $lista = array())
{
    if($contador < 10)
    {
        $lista[] = $contador;
        $contador++;
        return minhaFuncao($contador, $lista);
    }

    return $lista;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Exatamente o que eu estava tentando. Havia pensado que o array zerava a cada vez que era chamado dentro da função.